# Save information about cordova packages

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using several cordova packages in my Ionic app. Below is the command that I use for installing a Cordova package

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

This works fine. The challenge is that this information does not get saved in package.json.

So, the next developer who has pulled my code also has to manually install the cordova plugins that I have installed.

I am looking for something like 'npm install xxxx --save' which would save the plugin/packages information somewhere and then a command that would pull the packages automatically.

In some projects, I have seen the following in package.json

```
 "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-camera",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar"
  ]
```

However, I am not able to find that command that would add these to package.json or should it be updated manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cordova 4.3.0 or higher the plugins you are using should be documented in and restored from the config.xml automatically. See the docs [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html).

See also the docs on [saving plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html#saving-plugins) and on [restoring plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html#restoring-plugins).